# how to alert user on click of browser back button in angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular4-router

how to alert the user on click of browser back button in angular 4?

**`onpopstate` gets called even when the page loads for the first time**

```
import {  PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';

    constructor( private platformLocation: PlatformLocation) {
        platformLocation.onPopState(() => {
          console.log("onPopState called");
          window.alert("your data will be lost");
        })
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: canDeactivate is Angular way of handling the browser back

Comment: Check my below solution

Comment: its working ..Thanks @ShreyKejriwal

Comment: Hi @ranjith, please upvote if the solution was useful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a candeactivate guard

can-deactivate-guard.service.ts

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {CanDeactivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate, 
                currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
                nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot
                ) : Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return component.canDeactivate();
  }
}
```

in your routing setting

```
const route: Route = [
  {path: '', component: AppComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]}
]
```

Provide your can Deactivate guards in your app.module in providers array.

Consider the following component where I have variable to check changes Saved

```
export class AppComponent implements CanComponentDeactivate {
   changesSaved = false;
   onUpdateServer() {
     this.changesSaved = true;
   }
   canDeactivate() {
      if(this.changesSaved) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return confirm('Do you want to discard changes');
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ngOnDestroy` inside the component.It will be called automatically when component is going to be destroyed and you can then alert any warning.