# How to restrict users from pressing back button in browser | angular 6

Tags: angular, browser

I am using Angular 6 for my project. I need to restrict users from clicking on the back button in browser and show alert message instead.

Comment: may be it is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/48699942/5566405

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a class to implement "[CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate)" interface where you can handle the events. Try redirecting to the active URL itself with **location.go()** like this on the back button event.

`location.go('getTheCurrentPathToRedirect');`

Something like below one:

```
export class CanDeactivateBack implements CanDeactivate<any> {
    constructor(public location: Location, public router: Router) {}
    canDeactivate(component: any, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        //YourConditionIfBackButttonPress - check for the history back click
        if (YourConditionIfBackButttonPress) {
            let urlPath = this.router.createUrlTree([], currentRoute);
            let curUrlPath = urlPath.toString();
            this.location.go(curUrlPath);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't run the above code. Its just an Idea so you can start with. Let me check and update later.